# Audio Crackles on Windows

Tags: windows-10, audio

I've been experiencing audio crackling on my Windows 10 laptop for a number of months now. It happens most often when I pause an audio source, like Spotify, and then play it again sometime later. I can usually resolve the issue by restarting the audio application but occasionally I have to unplug/plug in my headphones or restart the computer.

I've tried many things:

- Increasing CPU priority of audio applications
- Reinstalling audio drivers
- Reinstalling audio applications
- Changing Power Options
- Changing the Windows settings for the sample rate and bit depth of the audio playback device

None of those worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my issue was to disable Intel Rapid Storage Technology (RST)'s "Link Power Management".

Steps:

- Do a Windows search for "Intel" and check for an "Intel Rapid Storage Technology" application
- Click the "Performance" button at the top
- Click the "Disable" link beside "Link Power Management"
- Restart Windows